# Corona Button not passing focus to scrollView

Tags: button, lua, widget, scrollview, coronasdk

**I am having an issue with scrolling when buttons are on the scrollView. The problem is the issue of events not being handled properly. All attempts to pass focus to the scrollView have proven fruitless. An observation I have made is that in this following code, it is not printing back to me, this is even after I was scrolling correctly without the buttons in the way of it.**

```
local function scrollListener( event )

local phase = event.phase
if ( phase == "began" ) then print( "Scroll view was touched" )
elseif ( phase == "moved" ) then print( "Scroll view was moved" )
elseif ( phase == "ended" ) then print( "Scroll view was released" )
end

-- In the event a scroll limit is reached...
if ( event.limitReached ) then
    if ( event.direction == "up" ) then print( "Reached top limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "down" ) then print( "Reached bottom limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "left" ) then print( "Reached left limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "right" ) then print( "Reached right limit" )
    end
end

return true
```

end

**Here is the actual code being used for the scene:**

function scene:enterScene(event)

```
--local yell=audio.play(ahhh, {channel=1, loops=0, fadein=0})

--Creating the Background
local background=display.newImageRect("background.png", 320, 580)
background.x=160
background.y=240


--Creating the scroll view
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
    top = 10,
    left = 10,
    width = 300,
    height = 500,
    scrollWidth = 300,
    scrollHeight = 500,
    horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
    listener = scrollListener
}

local button = {}


local yCount = 0


for i = 1 , 11 do
    button[i] = widget.newButton{
        label = "Button " .. i,
        left = 0,
        id = button[i],
        top = yCount,
        width = 300,
        height = 100,
        defaultFile = "menuButton.png",
        onEvent = handleButtonEvent
    }

    yCount = yCount + 100
    scrollView:insert(button[i])

end



--local background=display.newRect(160, 270, 320, 510)
--scrollView:insert( background )

local menu=display.newImageRect("menu2.png", 90, 50)
menu.x=50
menu.y=-15



function menu:touch(event)
    if event.phase=="began" then
        --local illBeBack=audio.play(terminator,{channel=1, loops=0, fadein=0})
        display.remove(menu)
        display.remove(taskBar)
        display.remove(background)

        taskBar = nil
        background = nil
        menu = nil
        storyboard.gotoScene("menu")
    end
    return true
end
menu:addEventListener("touch", menu)
```

end

--Button Event Handler

local function handleButtonEvent( event )

```
local phase = event.phase

if ( phase == "moved" ) then
    local dy = math.abs( ( event.y - event.yStart ) )
    -- If the touch on the button has moved more than 10 pixels,
    -- pass focus back to the scroll view so it can continue scrolling
    if ( dy > 10 ) then
        scrollView:takeFocus( event )
    end
end
return true
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing 'local' from the 'handleButtonEvent' and 'scrollListener' functions, along with removing 'local' from the 'scrollView' widget

So it appears that in corona, or at least the program I am making, that globals must be used a lot more than what they should be, unless someone else has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the event.phase into scrollView like this:

```
scrollView:takeFocus(event.phase)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still having all the same issues as before, also wouldn't that just send the phase only, and not the entire event?